# Delete all Images on one Slide with VBA in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, image, powerpoint

I want to delete only images on a slide with VBA in PowerPoint.

With the given code all shapes on the slide are being deleted.

```
Sub DeleteAllPictures()

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Range.Delete

End Sub
```

The Images are added with the following Code:

```
    Sub InsertPic_EAP()
  'Insert Picture
 ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="U:\Automatisierung\3D_Module\EAP.png", _
   LinkToFile:=msoTrue, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=260, Top:=110, _
   Width:=270, Height:=250

 ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="U:\Automatisierung\Bilder_AP\EAP_01.png", _
   LinkToFile:=msoTrue, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=620, Top:=220, _
   Width:=270, Height:=115

    End Sub
```

How do I modify the code to only select and delete the Images on the slide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will work for you: **Edit - For Linked Pictures**

```
Sub DeleteAllPictures()

Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes

    If shp.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then
        shp.Delete
    End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Looping through all the shapes in the slide and deleting if it is a picture.

Comment: Nothing happens when I run the Code. :/

Comment: Are you sure that Slide is the 1st slide ?? And there are pictures on it ?

Comment: I am sure. Maybe the Problem is that the Pictures are added with an macro:

Sub InsertPic_EAP()
  'Insert Picture
 ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="U:\Automatisierung\3D_Module\EAP.png", _
   LinkToFile:=msoTrue, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=260, Top:=110, _
   Width:=270, Height:=250
… etc.

Comment: Well the macro in answer should delete these images. Can you share the Slide ?

Comment: I tried it again and for the Pictures that are added normally the Code is perfect. But the Images that I added with the macro still stay on the slide.

Comment: Try the Answer Now. I have changed it to LinkedPicture. As with Macro you are pasting Linked Picture. @Bartek

Comment: Perfect! But the Code is working only partially. I have to run the Code 3 times till all the Images are deleted. Have a solution for this?

Comment: Ideally the code should remove all the Linked Pictures in one go. Can't say why it isn't. I can take a look if you can share the slide.

Comment: For the Moment I just looped the macro several times! Thanks a lot, Mikku.

Comment: @ Bartek: I experienced the same problem you describe. All images added by a macro didn't work. Changing "msoLinkedPicture" to "msoPicture" solved it for me. Now all pictures get deleted in one go.